# How to assign a combination of string and a variable to another variable?

Tags: perl

How can I assign a combination of string and a variable to another variable?

For example, I need to prepare a piece of code that I need to write in a file based on the `if` condition match. Here `$mod` and `$param` are variables and rest of them is just plain text that I need to write in a file.

```
$mode = "abc";
$param = "parameter";
if (${mod} == "xyz") {
$tmp_var = $mod #(
$param
) func_cell 
   (/*AUTO*/);
} else {
$tmp_var = $mod  func_cell 
   (/*AUTO*/);
}
# Here I will write `$tmp_var` inbetween other text in my file.
```

If I run above code, I see `syntax errors` like `(Missing semicolon on previous line?)`. I am new to `Perl`. Can someone help me fixing the syntax?

Comment: `${mod}` is presumably `${mode}`, right? Or do you have both `$mod` and `$mode`?

Comment: mod is just a variable name.

Comment: That's why I'm wondering why you're doing `${mod}` instead of `$mod`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.` is the string concatenation operator in Perl.

```
$y = "bar";
$z = "foo" . $y;
print $z;        # "foobar"
```

Some expressions inside pairs of `"`double-quotes`"` are also interpolated (the interpolation rules can get pretty complicated), so writing a string expression with interpolated variables is another way to concatenate strings.

```
$y = "bar";
$z = "foo$y";
print $z;        # "foobar";

$z = "$ybaz";    # this won't work, looks for a single var named '$ybaz'
$z = "${y}baz";  # but this will. I told you it gets complicated
print $z;        # "barbaz"
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate string by `.` operator for anything; constant or variable, it may be origially numeric/other type that'd be coerced into string type
some mistakes on here;

```
if (${mod} == "xyz") {
$tmp_var = $mod #(
$param
) func_cell 
   (/*AUTO*/);
} else {
$tmp_var = $mod  func_cell 
   (/*AUTO*/);
}
```

if `${mod}` is meant as scalar/plain variable; it'd be $mod, `{}` after a variable is mostly to make use a reference
test $mod == "xyz" will be wrong if meant for string test, as it's operator are `eq, ne, lt, gt, le, ge`
any `== != >= <= < >` symbol is for numeric test
I guess you mean
`$tmp_var = $mod.$func_cell`
if the last is simple/scalar variable or

`$tmp_var = $mod.$func_cell`
if as such obtained of subroutine return